# What software is available on OSX for working with DEMs?

Tags: convert, dem, osx, mosaic, xyz

I have several adjacent DEM files and would like to combine them into a mosaic and then export to DEM and TXT. I know a Windows solution is to use MICRODEM but before installing Windows 7 I would like to know if there is a Mac (OSX) based option.

Comment: you can use MICRODEM if you use Parallels for Mac - http://www.parallels.com/products/desktop/ (Has worked flawlessly for ArcGIS on the Mac for years.)

Answer (score 3):

Try `gdal_merge`.  You can grab the GDAL framework from [William Kyngesburye's website](http://www.kyngchaos.com/software%3aframeworks).

Instructions for utilizing `gdal_merge` can be found [here](http://gdal.org/gdal_merge.html).

Answer (score 1):

why MICRODEM with Parallels when you have many native possibilities on Mac ? .

Applications:

- GRASS GIS from [William Kyngesburye's website](http://www.kyngchaos.com/software/grass), for example, the best one.
- [GvSIG](http://gvsigmac.blogspot.be/) which can handle DEMs
- [OSSIM and OSSIMPLANET](http://trac.osgeo.org/ossim/)  specialized in working with DEMs
- [LandSerf](http://www.landserf.org/) specialized in working with DEMs

in the shell:

- GDAL as as pointed out by ShaunLangley
- Python with geospatial modules
- [R](http://www.r-project.org/) with  [spatial packages](http://cran.r-project.org/web/views/Spatial.html)
- and also the [Generic Mapping Tools](http://gmt.soest.hawaii.edu/)